# Как отключить яндекс советник у пользователя?

Tags: javascript, яндекс-советник

Нужно, чтобы любой пользователь, заходя на сайт в карточку товара, не видел [яндекс советник](http://prntscr.com/cerxmd), как его заблокировать?

Comment: На этот [скрипт](https://github.com/SerjoPepper/kick_sovetnik)  посмотрите

Answer (score 3):

Во-первых, яндекс.советник устанавливается как плагин в браузер. 
**Согласно документации (как отключить):**

> Перейдите на страницу    → Настройки → Дополнения и нажмите Отключить
>   в блоке Советника.

То есть таким образом делаем вывод, что отключить его может только пользователь самостоятельно в своем браузере.

Есть альтернативный (небезопасный) вариант как убрать советника: https://github.com/SerjoPepper/kick_sovetnik

Comment: А на сайте, можно как-то отключить? может есть какой-то скрипт или ещё что-то. в браузере это понятно - но не вариант.

Comment: прикрепил к ответу ссылку с комментария, но в некоторых случаях данный скрипт "ломает" сайт. Так что на ваш страх и риск.